# Apache .htacces redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I try to create redirect rules. I have two URLs www.example.com/speak and www.example.com/speaking. I added below lines to my .htaccess

```
RewriteRule speaking$ /?utm_source=offline&utm_medium=books&utm_campaign=bookmarks_uk [NC,QSA,R=301]
RewriteRule speak$ /?utm_source=offline&utm_medium=bookmarks&utm_campaign=english_course [NC,QSA,R=301,L]
```

but each time I'm redirected to /?utm_source=offline&utm_medium=books&utm_campaign=bookmarks_uk.

I swapped them around but it didn't work.

Any idea?

Comment: Do you want a redirect (URL change) or rewrite?

Answer (score 1):

Those rules should work fine, but can be improved to cater for the trailing slash. Also use `^` to mark the beginning of the string and `$` to mark the end of the string.

```
RewriteRule ^speaking/?$ /?utm_source=offline&utm_medium=books&utm_campaign=bookmarks_uk [NC,QSA,R=301]
RewriteRule ^speak/?$ /?utm_source=offline&utm_medium=bookmarks&utm_campaign=english_course [NC,QSA,R=301,L]
```

I suspect you problem is browser caching. Try clearing your browser cache and restarting your browser.

Comment: Thank you. I added L option to top rule and it works! I had to clear browser cache as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You are being redirected because you are using the `R=301` flag. If you are trying to access `/speaking` and show the contents of `/?utm_source=offline&utm_medium=books&utm_campaign=bookmarks_uk`, then you need to remove the flag in question.

Your resulting rules should look like this:

```
RewriteRule ^speaking/?$ /?utm_source=offline&utm_medium=books&utm_campaign=bookmarks_uk [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^speak/?$ /?utm_source=offline&utm_medium=bookmarks&utm_campaign=english_course [NC,QSA,L]
```